# PHP Array how to tell if character not found?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an example code like this :

```
$a = "A";
$b = array("A", "B", "C");

foreach ($b as $value) 
{
    $checkName = strpos($a, $value);

    if($checkName !== false)
    {
        echo "K";
    }
    else 
    {
       echo "b";
    }
}
```

if i run above code, will show "KBB".

how when we already found the string we only echoing "K" ?
so what i want is,

1. Find a string in array,
2. if found echo k,
3. if not found echo b.

Comment: You need to break out of the loop....now go google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a question of simple linear search:

```
$a = "A";
$b = array("A", "B", "C");

$found = FALSE;

foreach ($b as $value) 
{
    if($value == $a)
    {
        $found = TRUE;
        break;
    }
}

if($found)
    echo 'k';
else
    echo 'b';
```

Hope, it helps.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.

```
if(in_array($a, $b)) {
    echo "K";
} else {
    echo "B";
}
```

But the above code only echo K if it is completely match. If you need to find a character is in a string array, you should use:

```
if(strpos($value, $a) === false) {
    echo "B";
} else {
    echo "K";
}
```

Comment: but wait, if i have a string not completely match, how to do it? @AkiEru

Comment: @AkiEru : how about the string is not completely match?